# How do I create a simple template that adds a category in a Mediawiki template?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I am trying to create a template that adds the page to a category (in a second step also a short header text) but I fail succeeding. Right now I have the following:

```
<noinclude>This is a template to mark articles that needs an update. All these articles are listed under {{:Category:Articles that needs update}}</noinclude>
<includeonly>{{Category:Articles that needs update}}</includeonly>
```

This does not tag the page with the wanted category and the category-page does not contain any link to the category in question.

Comment: @ale: When should I use the template-tag and when should I not?

Comment: [tag:template] seems too generic to me. If you look at the questions with that tag it is used with a ton of different web apps. I don't know that there are enough questions about templates in Mediawiki to justify a [tag:mediawiki-templates], but it may not be unreasonable. I note we already have [tag:wikipedia-templates].

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I suggest it to be removed then. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Square brackets instead of braces.

```
<noinclude>This is a template to mark articles that needs an update. All these articles are listed under [[:Category:Articles that needs update]]</noinclude>
<includeonly>[[Category:Articles that needs update]]</includeonly>
```

Comment: The template works but does not do what I want. It adds the category to the page I include the template in, but when visiting the category, it lists no pages. Is there a solution to this or should I be doing this in another way?

Comment: It seems to be working but with a delay, the page did not appear within some minutes, some hours later it worked!

Comment: Was the cached version. To referesh the page, click edit, change edit at the end of the url to purge and enter.